# Why is my variable not printing to the screen?

Tags: angular

In my angular program, I'm trying to get the number of years that an employee has worked at a company and based on those years, assign them a certain number of hours off. I created a function that I believe should work, but nothing is getting printed to the screen and I'm not sure why.

Here's the relevant parts of my .ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { EmpInfoService } from './emp-info.service';
import { TrackerComponent } from './tracker.component';
import { EmpInfo } from './emp-info'; 

@Component({
    selector: 'pto-summary',
    templateUrl: `./summary.component.html`,
    styleUrls: ['./summary.component.css']
})

export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit{

    empInfo: EmpInfo[];
    @Input() selectedEmployee: number;
    ptoBase: number = 0;
    
    constructor(private empInfoService: EmpInfoService) { }
    
    getEmpInfo(): void {
        this.empInfoService.getEmpInfos().then(
            empInfo => {
                this.empInfo = empInfo.sort((a, b) =>
                    a.LastName < b.LastName ? -1 : b.LastName < a.LastName ? 1 : 0);
            });
    }
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getEmpInfo();
    }
    
    getPtoBase() {
        if (this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].AdjustedStart != null) {
            var time = (new Date()).valueOf() - (new Date(this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].AdjustedStart)).valueOf();
            time = time / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 356);
            if (time < 1) {
                return this.ptoBase = 10;
            }
            else if (time >= 1 && time < 5) {
                return this.ptoBase = 15;
            }
            else if (time >= 5 && time < 10) {
                return this.ptoBase = 20;
            }
            else {
                return this.ptoBase = 25;
            }
        }
        else {
            time = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].Anniversary;
            if (time < 1) {
                return this.ptoBase = 10;
            }
            else if (time >= 1 && time < 5) {
                return this.ptoBase = 15;
            }
            else if (time >= 5 && time < 10) {
                return this.ptoBase = 20;
            }
            else {
                return this.ptoBase = 25;
            }
        }
    }
```

and here's where the function and value are in my html

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" style="overflow-x:auto;" onload="getPtoBase()">
  <fieldset>
    <h4>PTO</h4>

    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
          <label class="col-xs-2"> Base </label>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input [disabled]="isDisabled" class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoBase" value="{{ptoBase}}" name="ptoBase" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  </fieldset>
```

Comment: `timevar` would need to be a property on the component, or if you are trying to access a method, use `{{ timevar() }}`.  Right now, I don't see anything like that in your component.

Comment: I figured that as long as ptobase had changed in the function, the changed would be reflected when ran

Comment: If you create a `time` property and use that instead of the time var, it would work. However, you'd still have to call `getPtoBase()` somewhere to update the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use two-way data binding.

```
<input [disabled]="isDisabled" class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoBase" [(value)]=ptoBase name="ptoBase" />
```

As far as I know `{{}}` works only for plain text.

Comment: i'm getting the correct number in my variable, it's just not printing to the screen

Comment: Your variable is not declared anywhere.

Comment: `ptoBase: number = 0;`

Comment: Ahh ok. The point was pto variable, not timevar. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: sorry, that my fault for not specifically saying that in the beginning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147491/discussion-between-maciej-sobala-and-rcarc).